# How to check for user agent for all requests?

Tags: go, user-agent, go-gin

I have a function that defines a user_agent:

```
func getUserAgent(c *gin.Context) bool {
    ua := ua.Parse(c.Request.UserAgent())
    if ua.Bot {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Also, I have routes, and I need to call getUserAgent in each route and if it true - use my routes , if false -  return smth else. How can i do this?

Routes:

```
func Routes(router *gin.Engine) {

    router.GET("/user_agent", getUserAgent)

    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {

        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", nil)
    })
    router.GET("/:some_urls", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "index.html", nil)
    })

    categories := router.Group("/categories")
    {
        categories.GET("/", controller.GetAllCategories)
    }
    router.GET("/category_detail", controller.GetCategoriesById)
    products := router.Group("/products")
    {
        products.GET("/", controller.GetAllProducts_by_multi_params)
    }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can make the `getUserAgent`  as middleware like below
every router will go into the `getUserAgent` first then run the handler.

```
router.Use(getUserAgent)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to check if getUserAgent returns false then use my routes. Question edited

Comment: which is my router?  I don't want you mean.
I guess you mean if the `getUserAgent ` return false
should return 400 or other error status code?